# Сложноподчиненное предложение с перечислением развернутых вопросов во второй части. Какие знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация, поэзия

Есть такой текст в стихах:

Куда летишь ты, мир подлунный,
Куда несёшь свои мечты,
Когда людей живущих думы
Всё больше алчностью полны;

Когда старуха на погосте,
Игрушку вам рукой даря...

И далее еще пара аналогичных вопросов. Не очень понятно, в какой части ставить вопросительный знак: после каждого вопроса или после всех перечисленных?

Answer (score 1):

Стихотворение, мне кажется, стилизовано под поэзию XIX века (в пользу этого говорит и употребление устаревшего словосочетания [*подлунный мир*](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/165778) (= вселенная)).
А вот вопросительный знак, думаю, нужно поставить или в самом конце, или можно дополнительно после первой строчки (тогда она акцентируется, а подлежащее "ты" легко восстанавливается из первого предложения).
Если придаточные однородны, то после "полны" ставится запятая, а не точка с запятой.

Куда летишь ты, мир подлунный?
Куда несёшь свои мечты,
Когда людей живущих думы
Всё больше алчностью полны,

Когда старуха на погосте,
Игрушку вам рукой даря <...>?

**Дополнение** (17.12 2022)
В качестве примера (не девятнадцатый век, конечно, но *серебряный*; Дон Аминадо. Как рассказать?):

> Как объяснишь им чувство это
> И как расскажешь на словах —
> Тревогу зимнего рассвета
> На петербургских островах,
>
> Когда, замучившись, несется
> Шальная тройка поутру,
> Когда, отстегнутая, бьется
> Медвежья полость на ветру?

Answer (score 0):

Можно поставить запятую после каждого вопросительного предложения, а можно после всех перечисленных вопросов. Это зависит от задумки автора. К стихам часто применимы понятия "авторское", "авторская пунктуация".